# 'libcore.io.ErrnoException' debugging app on Emulator disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

While debugging an app on the Android emulator I'm getting the following exception :

```
Exception 'libcore.io.ErrnoException' occurred in thread '<1> main' at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.stat(ForwardingOs.java:131)
```

And debugging is halted. If I just run the application, it works fine. If I create a new application, I can debug it. Anyone knows what's going on ?

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2.

UPDATE:I did a clean download of all the sources, recompiled and then was able to debug again....

Comment: Can you please try to set your app as the "debug app" ? See: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html -> If it helped let me know so I can post as an answer :)

Comment: I already did, it doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

In studio click on **Debug** >>> **View Breakpoints** and if **Java Exception Breakpoints** is checked then **un-check** it. DONE.